# Async and Await commands compile without errors but will not let my Windows Form be responsive

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, asynchronous

I have an excel sheet with various toolbox items on it.  I have a drop down menu that allows the user to select a value and hit a "run" button (my button1) and that all works fine, assuming data is within the Excel sheet and currently that is done manually.  But if I want to add a second button (button2) that will "refresh" data from an SQL Server automatically, it runs... but not asynchronously.  Here is my button2:

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Excel = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application;
        var activebook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook;
        var ws = Excel.ActiveSheet;
        SQLServer server = new SQLServer();
        int t = await Task.Run(() => server.getInfo(activebook, ws, Excel));     
    }
```

The code runs fine, but I do not want to have to make the users wait for 6000 lines of excel sheet to be filled before the Excel window is responsive.  Am I doing something wrong here?

### EDIT

I apologize for the confusion, I am still pretty new to this site and did not meant to cause so much confusion.  I am trying to run this method:

```
 public void getInfo(Workbook book, Worksheet activesheet,     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app)
    {          
        SqlConnection cnn;

        string connectionstring = "#########";
        string sql = null; 

        ////***Opening SQL Database

        connectionstring = "Data Source=########;Initial Catalog=BrightreeData;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=######;Password=######";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        cnn.Open(); 
        activesheet.Range["K" + 1].Value = "Connected";


        ////** Write your Sql Query here
        sql = "SELECT [StopReason], [SOKey], [NickName] FROM [BrightreeData].[dbo].[SalesOrder] Where [StopReason] = 'Ineligible Policy' ORDER BY [SOKey]";           


        ///*** Preparing to retrieve value from the database
        SQL.DataTable dtable = new SQL.DataTable();

        SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
        SQL.DataSet ds = new SQL.DataSet();
        dscmd.Fill(dtable);
        int count = dtable.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < dtable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {               

            try
            {
     check: activesheet.Range["C" + 1].Value = (i + 1) + " out of " + count + " rows";
            soService.DataFetchServiceResponseUsingSalesOrder salesorder = soAction.SalesOrderFetchByBrightreeID(dtable.Rows[i]["SOKey"].ToString());
            activesheet.Range["J" + (8 + i)].Value = dtable.Rows[i]["NickName"];
            activesheet.Range["A" + (8 + i)].Value = salesorder.Items[0].SalesOrderInsuranceInfo.Payors[1].payorPolicyInfo.Name.ToString();
            activesheet.Range["D" + (8 + i)].Value = salesorder.Items[0].SalesOrderInsuranceInfo.Payors[1].payorPolicyInfo.PolicyNumber;
            //If the current row has the same policy as the last row, it is a repeat and nothing worth grabbing that data.
            //
            //    Eventually add something at the end of the program that deletes rows that are blank?...for now I will manually delete empty rows.
            if(activesheet.Range["D" + (8 + i)].Value == activesheet.Range["D" + (7 + i)].Value & activesheet.Range["D" + (8 + i)].Text != "")
            {
                activesheet.Range["C" + (8 + i)].Value = "Repeat Patient";
                count--;
                i++;
                goto check;
            }
            activesheet.Range["J" + (8 + i)].Value = "St Lukes";
            activesheet.Range["K" + (8 + i)].Value = System.DateTime.Today.Date;
            string ptID = Convert.ToString(salesorder.Items[0].SalesOrderClinicalInfo.Patient.BrightreeID);
            ptService.DataFetchServiceResponseUsingPatient ptSearch = ptAction.PatientFetchByBrightreeID(ptID);
            activesheet.Range["B" + (8 + i)].Value = ptSearch.Items[0].PatientGeneralInfo.Name.First;
            activesheet.Range["C" + (8 + i)].Value = ptSearch.Items[0].PatientGeneralInfo.Name.Last;
            activesheet.Range["E" + (8 + i)].Value = ptSearch.Items[0].PatientGeneralInfo.BirthDate;
            activesheet.Range["L" + (8 + i)].Value = ptSearch.Items[0].PatientGeneralInfo.PtID;
            }catch
            {
                activesheet.Range["B" + (8 + i)].Value = "Error getting patient information";
            }

        }   

    }
```

using this call:

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Excel = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application;
        var activebook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook;
        var ws = Excel.ActiveSheet;
        SQLServer server = new SQLServer();
        await Task.Run(() => server.getInfo(activebook, ws, Excel));     
    }
```

An error gets thrown at the last line in my button2_Click() Method.

```
 An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException'
occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot implicitly convert type 'type' to 'object'
```

Comment: You're doing the same thing twice, aren't you?  Once synchronously, then awaiting asynchronously for it to run again on a background thread? I'd say just remove the first call to `getInfo`.

Comment: Note that you're calling `server.getInfo` twice - once in `Task.Run`, once without. In any case, decoupling the reading of the data from filling the sheet is a good idea :)

Comment: *Please* post code as text rather than just an image. You've made it much harder to work with your question... but yes, you appear to be calling `getInfo` twice... why?

Comment: As an aside, is the Excel API threadsafe?  That is, are you allowed to add data to an Excel sheet from a thread other than the one that created it?

Comment: @adv12 you can get away with it, but each call will be marshalled back to the application thread.  The end result is that doing lots of interop on another thread is an order of magnitude slower.

Comment: Re your second error, presumably `getInfo` doesn't return anything?  If so, remove `int t =`.

Comment: @CharlesMager I have updated my question.  I was pasting my code around my program and I did not realize I had it calling my GetInfo() twice.  It now spits back an error saying that I can not convert its' type.  I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: What is the signature of the `getInfo` method?

Comment: @CharlesMager I took away the `int n =`  but I still get the same runtime error.

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Comment: @YacoubMassad I have updated the question in hopes that it is now more easily read.  My apologies.

Comment: @Luaan  I updated my question, I hope this helps :P

Comment: You also may want to look in to the [OpenXML SDK for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) it will let you read and write `xlsx` files directly without the itnerop API, it is a much faster API. However it does not interact with a already open instance of Excel, if you need to do that you may be stuck with the interop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
await Task.Run((Action)(() => server.getInfo(activebook, ws, Excel)));
```

For some reason (probably because the arguments you pass are COM objects), the system treats the arguments and therefore the method call as dynamic, and will falsely think that the delegate you pass will return a value.

If you move your mouse over `Task.Run` in visual studio, you should see that the system is trying to invoke this overload:

```
Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<TResult> function)
```

where `TResult` is `dynamic`.

Comment: I tried your change and the compiler gives me errors.  I tried both the System.Action as well as the Microsoft.Office.Excel.Action call but both don't seem to like this.

Comment: Sorry, I forget a bracket. Updated the answer.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you very much!  I owe you big time.  I had messed with the Action class but was not really sure how it worked.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Rinktacular, glad to help.